# How to change color of tabs in silverlight navigation application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

I created a navigation app using silverlight templates. I do have 4 tabs named `Home, About, Info, Maps` Now when i select anyone it works fine but it doesn't look like which one is selected. As there is no color change for the selected one tab.

Please suggest me how can i change the color of selected Tab ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code sample of the so-called tabs ? Are you using a tab control with multiple tab items or are you talking about the link buttons that come in the main page as default links ?

Comment: yes the Home and About buttons that comes in Default templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never played explicitly with this myself, but with the default styles this behaviors is there

```
            <Border x:Name="LinksBorder" Style="{StaticResource LinksBorderStyle}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel" Style="{StaticResource LinksStackPanelStyle}">

                    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link2" Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
                                 NavigateUri="/About" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="About"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
```

In the code behind:

```
    // After the Frame navigates, ensure the HyperlinkButton representing the current page is selected
    private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //This is to hide/show the leftside menu
        ApplyConfiguration(ApplicationConfiguration.GetConfiguration());

        foreach (UIElement child in LinksStackPanel.Children)
        {
            HyperlinkButton hb = child as HyperlinkButton;
            if (hb != null && hb.NavigateUri != null)
            {
                if (hb.NavigateUri.ToString().Equals(e.Uri.ToString()))
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "ActiveLink", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "InactiveLink", true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice the goto state Active of inactive. This code comes from the default template of a navigation silverlight project.
Keeping the StaticResource of the style should fix the issue. Then you could go and create your own style